# NGINX to Apache(rewriting)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

Could someone please try converting this into .htaccess for me? I am not good at apache, and my new server setup needs apache:

```
listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/pgcp.pingrglobe.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/pgcp.pingrglobe.key;
    server_name pgcp.pingrglobe.com;
    root /var/www/html/pingrglobe.com/ctrlpanel;
    index index.html index.php;
    error_page 404 https://www.pingrglobe.com/404.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    } 
    rewrite ^/blog/blogpost/(.+)$ /blog/blogpost?post=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/viewticket/(.+)/(.*)$ /viewticket?tid=$1&$2 last;
    rewrite ^/vemail/(.+)$ /vemail?eid=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/serversettings/(.+)$ /serversettings?srvid=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/notification/(.+)$ /notification?id=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/viewreport/(.+)$ /viewreport?srvid=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/removeserver/(.+)$ /removeserver?srvid=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/staffviewticket/(.+)/(.*)$ /staffviewticket?tid=$1&$2 last;
    rewrite ^/activate/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /activate?user=$1&code=$2&email=$3 last;
    rewrite ^/activate2/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /activate2?user=$1&code=$2&email=$3 last;
    rewrite ^/passwordtoken/(.+)/(.*)/(.*)$ /passwordtoken?user=$1&token=$2&email=$3 last;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of that stuff needs to go into your server/vhost's config, like the ssl stuff, the document root stuff, the server name, etc. You'll need to read the apache documentation for that. The rewrite stuff, however, can go in the htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.pingrglobe.com/404.html

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/blogpost/(.+)$ /blog/blogpost?post=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^viewticket/(.+)/(.*)$ /viewticket?tid=$1&$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^vemail/(.+)$ /vemail?eid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^serversettings/(.+)$ /serversettings?srvid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^notification/(.+)$ /notification?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^viewreport/(.+)$ /viewreport?srvid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^removeserver/(.+)$ /removeserver?srvid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^staffviewticket/(.+)/(.*)$ /staffviewticket?tid=$1&$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^activate/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /activate?user=$1&code=$2&email=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^activate2/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /activate2?user=$1&code=$2&email=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^passwordtoken/(.+)/(.*)/(.*)$ /passwordtoken?user=$1&token=$2&email=$3 [L]
```

In general, you want to remove the leading slash from the match, and you want to replace the `last;` with `[L]`, and that's it.